# Getting ng-token-auth to work with devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, ionic-framework

I have a Rails and Ionic project.  The back-end uses the devise_token_auth Gem, and the front end ng-token-auth; these are supposed to work "seamlessly".

I've got everything working as far as registration and sign in, which returns a valid response object.  Hoever, any further requests after I use $state.go('app.somepage') result in 401 Unauthorized responses.

I get the sense that I'm not actually storing the token anywhere.  Can someone please help?

Here are some snippets:

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope', '$auth', '$state', function($scope, $auth, $state) {
    $scope.loginForm = {}
    $scope.handleLoginBtnClick = function() {
      console.log($scope.loginForm);
      $auth.submitLogin($scope.loginForm)
          .then(function(resp) {
            $state.go('app.feed');
          })
          .catch(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.errors);
          });
    };
```

State definition:

```
    .state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  resolve: {
    auth: function($auth) {
      return $auth.validateUser();
    }
  }

})
```

Resources:

```
factory('Post', ['railsResourceFactory', 'apiUrl', function (railsResourceFactory, apiUrl) {
    return railsResourceFactory({
        url: apiUrl + '/posts',
        name: 'post'
    });
}]).
```

And in PostsCtrl:

```
  $scope.loadFeed = function() {
    Post.query().then(function (posts) {
      $scope.posts = posts;
    }, function (error) {
      console.log( 'Did not get posts!'); ### THIS FIRES
    }).finally(function() {
      // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };
```

Login response object:

```
{"data":{"id":1,"provider":"email","uid":"1234","phone":null,"name":"Admin","image":null,"username":"admin"}}
```

Top of ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  ..yadayada...

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :phone
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :session

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :phone
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :session
  end
```

And some default models for User on the rails side.

Rails log:

```
Started GET "/posts" for 192.168.83.26 at 2015-02-24 23:29:02 -0500
Processing by PostsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"post"=>{}}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

If anyone can provide some insight that would be wonderful.  I'm happy to post more snippets as needed.

Comment: I haven't read your whole question yet but I wrote a whole post on Rails/Angular authentication with Lynn Dylan Hurley's libraries. https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Also, I don't know the answer to your question off hand, but what I would do in your situation is just spin up a blank new project and follow my tutorial, and see if it works. Then, if the tutorial works, see what's different between your project and the tutorial.

Comment: How are you getting on with this project? Im doing something very similar and having problems, have you open sourced?

Comment: Nope, but if you read my selected answer below, that should give you a clue.  I'm not permitted to open source the code. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution was rather simple.  It seems that in most of the examples everyone provides, they neglect to permit `access-token`, along with all the other CORS headers.

We used rack-cors for this, at the bottom of `config.ru`:

```
require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do

  # allow all origins in development
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
             :headers => :any,
             :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
             :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options]
  end
end
```

And then in ApplicationController.rb:

```
  before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers


  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end

  def add_allow_credentials_headers
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#section_5
    #
    # Because we want our front-end to send cookies to allow the API to be authenticated
    # (using 'withCredentials' in the XMLHttpRequest), we need to add some headers so
    # the browser will not reject the response
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  end
```

Comment: Not sure why this has gotten no votes or that this isn't covered in the base documentation. This was a must have for me, and I don't think we're doing anything unusual.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know how this can work without this. Although I only needed the `allow` block, none of the ApplicationController stuff. Furthermore, the allow block can go in your application.rb instead of config.ru if you're using Rails.

Comment: Thanks.  I see this is a problem for many people.  I've selected my own answer, since it actually was the solution, and I think your last comment is relevant.  We kind of used the jack-hammer approach.  Thanks for the tip re the code in config.ru.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm having the exact same problem (ionic, no acess-token header) and these solutions haven't helped. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This information may be relevant to you.

[jwako/ionic_rails_sample](https://github.com/jwako/ionic_rails_sample)

Answer (score 2):

As for my case, i use cookies to store the token. And whenever we do `$auth` methods in our Angular application, some of the methods will try to go to the devise route that you have defined in your Rails router and match/validate the token that is stored in any of the header's requests. (everytime you try to do http request! checkout your request headers using your browser inspector's if they're containing `uid` or `auth_token` if you're going to validate through the `GET` `/validate_token` (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr))

Since you didn't mention your route, we can assume `/auth`.

And those `$http` request provided by the `$auth` should be containing token to be authenticated the the Rails's Devise, and catch and store it to the browser's cookies whenever we do `$auth.submitLogin()`.

Here's the example on how it works in my previous project.

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', 'ipCookie', '$location',  function($q, ipCookie, $location) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if (ipCookie('access-token')) {
        config.headers['Access-Token'] = ipCookie('access-token');
        config.headers['Client'] = ipCookie('client');
        config.headers['Expiry'] = ipCookie('expiry');
        config.headers['Uid'] = ipCookie('uid');
      }
      return config;
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
        ipCookie.remove('access-token');
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}])
```

And set the token format to be looked like this (or custom as you need it)

```
$authProvider.configure({
  tokenValidationPath: '/auth/validate_token',
  signOutUrl: '/auth/sign_out',
  confirmationSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
  emailSignInPath: '/auth/sign_in',
  storage: 'cookies',
  tokenFormat: {
    "access-token": "{{ token }}",
    "token-type": "Bearer",
    "client": "{{ clientId }}",
    "expiry": "{{ expiry }}",
    "uid": "{{ uid }}"
  }
});
```

Don't forget to inject `ipCookie` (lookup for `angular-cookie` instead of `angular-cookies`) to the Interceptor since this is the cookie library that ng-token-auth use for cookies management.

Please comment below with questions if i didn't make myself clear enough. :D

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Also, we use local storage to store the token, which is equally effective.

Comment: I can verify that this solution works. I'm also using local storage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late,

But the problem is because you can't have the auth on cookies (only Android). So, you can try to use the localStorage to save your session info (on iOS & Android)

e.g

```
.config(function($authProvider) {
  $authProvider.configure({
    apiUrl: 'http://myprivateapidomain/api',
    storage: 'localStorage'
  });
})
```

You can  read more in the specific issue of the documentation: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/issues/93

Comment: We did this initially, but it didn't solve the problem.  It merely allowed us to store some session information and *pretend* that authentication had taken place.  Anyway, the whole idea of tokens is precisely to use session data.  This is a different solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

kinda late but for anyone who might try using ng-token-auth in an Ionic App, what I did to make it work (in my case) was to set the next configuration to my module:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  }]);
```

(I wasn't sending any cookie in my http request)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add configuration for the $authProvider. This example is in the readme of https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-token-auth'])
  .config(function($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.configure({
      apiUrl: 'http://api.example.com'
      authProviderPaths: {
        github: '/auth/github' // <-- note that this is different than what was set with github
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, authentication works initially, but then fails to translate into subsequent page requests.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the user you are trying to login with is invalid. When this happens the authorization header is empty and no access token is sent back in the response.

This happens here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/0d4de71/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb#L53